# Unable to install the latest release candidate of a Python library on GitHub

Tags: python, git, github, setup.py, airflow

I didn't succeed installing the latest [`airflow`](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow) release candidate.

Specifically, running `pip install -e git://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow.git@1.8.2rc4#egg=airflow` on the CL ended with:

```
File "/home/alex/Desktop/urban-physiology-toolkit/src/airflow/setup.py", line 87, in git_version
        assert tag == version, (tag, version)
    AssertionError: ('1.8.2rc4', '1.8.2')
```

Followed by the usual `pip` FAIL redtext.

The [offending code line](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/setup.py#L87) is a tag version check.

Installing from `HEAD` works fine.

Is this an error on my part, or an error in the `setup.py` configuration of the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry this is not a bug, but happens due to the Apache release process which required us not to change the source during/after voting. This means we need to keep "1.8.2" in version.py while the tag says something else.

If you want rc4 of airflow why don't you install from https://dist.apache.org/repos/dist/dev/incubator/airflow/1.8.2rc4/apache-airflow-1.8.2+incubating-bin.tar.gz

Answer (score 2):

It is a bug in [airflow.version](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/1.8.2rc4/airflow/version.py) — they've forgotten to change it to `1.8.2rc4`.

Please report the bug to the team.